# Clear Cookies on Session_End C#

Tags: c#, browser, saml, global-asax, sessionend

Is it possible to clear the browser's cookie on Session_End?
Given that there is no Context, no Request and no Response?

Also, it is not possible to put the values on the session instead of in the cookies. This is being done by a third party application.

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that the site is using SSO. And the cookie that I am trying to access is the SSO cookie.

Comment: no Request? then how you determin the Session_End..?

Comment: from the server-side. in-proc.

Comment: If you make sure that the your site's cookie have an appropriately short expiration time, the browser will do that for you.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do anything to the cookies in `Session_End` as that is called asynchronously by the server after a timeout. At that point there is no ongoing http request from the web browser, so there is no open communication channel to the browser.